# Reformatting an uploaded CSV file with lists / arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Main Road \t B \t 3
Main Road \t B \t 3
Main Road \t B \t 5
Example Road \t B \t 3
```

I need to output it like this:

```
Main Road,B3-B5
Example Road, B3
```

I need to:

- remove duplicated lines
- keep "Main Road" and "B" and "3" together
- check if two lines have a different name, if yes:

  - join them by the biggest number or bigger letter, depending which one is bigger

So far, I have tried at least seperating them into an associative array where the street name is the index:

```
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");

$separator = "\n";
$line = strtok($postData, $separator);

while ($line !== false) {

    $line = strtok($separator);
    $str = explode("\t",$line);
    list($a, list($b, $c)) = array($str[0], array($str[0], $str[0]));
    $arr[$str[0]] = $str[1].$str[2];
}

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo $key."=>".$value."<br>";
}
```

The problem is that is partly works:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\pietruska-crm\php\indexCSV.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\pietruska-crm\php\indexCSV.php on line 13
Hambrücker Straße=>C3
Langestraße=>C2
Weiherer Straße=>E3
```

Why is the offset undefined, but the output works?
How could I efficiently structure this? The documentation of PHP lists is rather vague on how to make arrays of lists.

Thanks

Comment: What do you do with `strtok`?

Comment: Splitting the CSV file, which is a string, into seperate lines. I tried processing the file without it, but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Oh you mean I could use strtok()  a second time? Will try this out.

Comment: Those notices occur only once, even though you are looping over multiple lines? Then you most likely have a line that doesn’t follow that format or an empty line somewhere in your input data. If a line does not contain a tabulator, then explode will return an array with only one element.

Comment: using strtok() a second time to split the current line into values did not work, because of a memory overflow. explode() is much better.

Comment: Yes, these notices only occur once. The data is formatted correctly, maybe I have a one-off error somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $array_of_lines = explode('\n',$postData);
    $array_of_lines = array_unique($array_of_lines); // delete duplicate strings
    $handled_array_of_lines = array();
    foreach ($array_of_lines as $line) {
        $array_of_values = explode("\t",$line); // now you have array('Road',B,3)
        $road = $array_of_values[0];
        $param = $array_of_values[1].$array_of_values[2];

        // check if the road meets first time or not; if not, add new param into this road entry
        if (!isset($handled_array_of_lines[$road])) {
            $handled_array_of_lines[$road] = $param;
        } else {
            $handled_array_of_lines[$road] .= '-'.$param;
        }
    }

    foreach ($handled_array_of_lines as $road => $param) {
        echo $road."=>".$param."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: Nope, same error I got: undefined offset "1" and "2" for $array_of_values[1] and $array_of_values[2]

Comment: $array_of_values is  array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "\n" } \n=>

Comment: There was an error in my code in first string. That's right `explode()`: `explode('\n',$postData)`. Try it again

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Only thing I had to change was in line 1, "\n" instead of '\n'